# Pyinstaller single exe does not work properly and apparently, there are many people having problems that go unsolved

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have two files, one bell.mp3 one main.py file, that  plays back bell.mp3 via subprocess.

If I do:

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

the Dist file ends up correctly, and everything works fine, The program runs in a directory.

This is the code for my file which i call pyinst_tester.py
it creates a text file, and plays a bell.mp3 file

```
#
from con import * # this is just a configuration file that has g='play' in it.
import subprocess


f=open(r'/home/godzilla/Desktop/Pyinstaller testing/testfile1','w')
f.write('This has worked')
f.close()
file='/home/godzilla/Desktop/Pyinstaller testing/data/bell.mp3'

if 'play' == g:

    subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/cvlc',file])
```

a single file is created, but if I delete the bell.mp3 file it doesn't work. In a single file isn't the bell.mp3 zipped inside the main.exe ? therefore, redundant as a separate file ?

What Is the point having a single file exe, if you need an adjacent file with all the mp3s inside?

Comment: You only packed the program, not its resources.

Comment: no i packed everything like this pyinstaller -F --add-data='bell.mp3' main.py ....you know i was wondering, ....the files pack inside the exe like a zip file yes ? so the original files can be deleted since their copies exist inside the exe? IS THAT ASSUMPTION CORRECT ? because someone said no it isnt to me .

Comment: As you see in my answer. Yes with --add-data / or add-binary the data files are included an extracted during run time into a temporary directory.

however the path name changes, it will be a sub directory of `sys._MEIPASS`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-L6g2VQCQA&feature=youtu.be please tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyinstaller has many features and if you want to include non python files (for example mp3 files) you have to do so **explicitly** with the `--add-binary` switch.

In one file mode the executable will be unpacked into a temporary directory prior to execution of the python code.

So how to write your code to access these data files.

You might want to look at the pyinstaller documention at following sections:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0

I personally place all my files in a separate directory. e.g. `data`.

If you place the file `bell.mp3` in the directory data, then you had to call pyinstaller with the option `--add-binary data:data`

in the one file mode the executable is extracted into a temporary directory
whose path you get get from the variable `sys._MEIPASS`
Your data directory will bi in the sub directory `data` of `sys._MEIPASS`

In my example I create a function, that will be able to locate the data files in normal python mode and in pyinstaller one file or one directory mode.
Just try it out it should be self explaining

simple example:
minitst.py

```
import os, sys
import time

is_frozen = getattr(sys, "frozen", False)
MYDIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

def data_fname(fname):
    if is_frozen:
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "data", fname)
    else:
        return os.path.join(MYDIR, "data", fname)

def main():
    print("This application is %s frozen" %
        ("" if is_frozen else "not"))
    print("executable =", sys.executable,
          "File =", __file__,
          "mydir =", MYDIR)
    if is_frozen:
        print("MEIPASS", sys._MEIPASS)
    fname = data_fname("tst.txt")
    print("will open", fname)
    with open(fname) as fin:
        print(fin.read())
    time.sleep(5)  # this shall allow to view the console e.g. on windows if clicking on the executable.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

now create a directory data and place a file "tst.txt"
data/tst.txt

```
Hello world
```

Now call

```
pyinstaller -F minitst.py --add-binary data:data -c
```

and call dist/minitst from a console.

The output should look like:

```
This application is  frozen
executable = /home/gelonida/so/pyinst/dist/minitst File = minitst.py mydir = /home/gelonida/so/pyinst
MEIPASS /tmp/_MEIKGqah9
will open /tmp/_MEIKGqah9/data/tst.txt
Hello
```

Now concerning your code. 
I compacted the code to determine the datadir a little, but it is the same logic as in the upper example

```
import os, sys
from con import * # this is just a configuration file that has g='play' in it.
import subprocess

basedir = getattr(sys, "_MEIPASS", os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
f=open('testfile1','w')
f.write('This has worked')
f.close()
file=os.path.join(basedir, 'data/bell.mp3')

if 'play' == g:

    subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/cvlc',file])
```

Comment: In the documentation it instructs you to add mp3 as —add-data=‘bell.mp3:.’ ....or ‘bell.mp3:soundfile’....I will try .your answer though and get back thanks

Comment: you can add files one by one, but I think this as annoying if you need other files lateron.
The most important thing is however, that you will find the mp3 file in sys._MEIPASS or one of its sub directories if you specify so. Looking up the file in this directory is probably what you were missing in your code, 

But as you never showed a minimal reproducible example I can just guess.

Comment: I updated my question with my actual code....do you suggest i include your code in it as ONE ??? like at the start?

Comment: I did what you said and the executable as -F was created. but after i pyinstalled, where exactly is the Hello World supposed to be written....if I run the script as unpacked i can see it at the end of the line printed, but after i pack it ? i cant see it...is there a window supposed to pop up with Hello world?

Comment: Hey man i have a youtube channel, if i upload there live what i do, can you help me out ??...i can upload a video of everything i do.....including python and bash code.

Comment: Perhaps you are running under windows or starting the executable with a double click. This opens perhaps a console  prints the text and closes it immediately.

I added now a sleep(5) a the end of the script. this should allow you to see the text printed out and the console closing after 5 seconds.

Also don't forget to add the `-c` switch to have a console application.

So `pyinstaller -F minitst.py --add-binary data:data -c`

Ideally for testing you should run the script from a console.

Comment: I modified the answer to also show the output of the script

Comment: Please see a video of what i did

Comment: You type `pyinstaller -F pyinst_tester.py --add-binary data:data -c` instead of `pyinstaller -F minitst.py --add-binary data:data -c`

Please try with the correct command. If it still doesn't work I still have quite some other suggestions, which I will tell you after trying this one,

Comment: apologies.
OK let's open a console in the same directory as you did in your video and type following commands.

`rm -rf build dist *.spec __pycache__  # just to clean up` 
Then type `type python ;  type pyinstaller ; python -V ; pyinstaller -v` and post the output.

Then type `pyinstaller -F minitst.py --add-binary data:data -c` and just confirn, that it says it completed sucessfully.

Now type `dist/minitst` and post the output.
If you have any problem it's better to only work on the console. Clicking on an executable may hide valuable information

Comment: python ; type pyinstaller ; python -V ; pyinstaller -v GIVES :  Python 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:39:04) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>....wierd, i am using 3.6.8

Comment: OK after doing dist/minitst...on the CONSOLE, it worked....i want this for a tkinter program i am going to distribute and would like a clickable version....i am going to try the bell now one sec.

Comment: So it only works inside the DIST folder, if i take it outside of the dist folder, it says, command not recognised  on the console?...whats up with that ?

Comment: Can you please integrate your code to my code, cause i am a little confused.

Comment: let's first check why you can't move files out of the dist folder.
please always post exactly what typed or did.
try following: `rm -rf build dist *.spec __pycache__` then `pyinstaller -F minitst.py --add-binary data:data -c` then  `mv dist/minitst .` ; then `./minidist` and post any strange output

Comment: I also enhanced my answer pleas check it, but please run all initial tests from the command line (even for the tkinter program), as potential issues will show up on the console.

Comment: THANKS VERY MUCH I OWE YOU A BEER, got it to work.....i am going to sleep now cause i am in greece, but i am going to have alot of questions while building my tkinter app....if you want,  i can create questions and you can answer them and get all the points.....thanks mate,,..phew, learned a lot. ...i take it if i want to bundle many files of different sorts pdf, mp3 txt etc....all i need to do is link each one to the base directory....? like you did.

Comment: Thanks for the beer :-) . Exactly. just add them to the data directory if it's a lot of files you can even create sub directories to structure your files. they will be included recursively

Comment: ...one more thing, about including an icon, i have to do the same thing?...cause the --icon way doesnt work.

Comment: I think it's better to post another question if you want to have a quick answer.
I never tried to add an icon. Not even sure this works for non windows applications.

Comment: i just posted a new question....if it doesnt work for windows apps, maybe i can do it manually?